nginx conditional logging not working
I want to block some unwanted traffic from my website using 7g-firewall for nginx. It works!
But now I want to write all 7g-firewall findings into a separate log file. This does not work as intended.
Here is my config (simplified to get to the point):
server {
  [ ... listen/server_name/root etc ...]

  # from 7g-firewall:
  map $http_user_agent $bad_ua_7g {
    default 0;
    "~*([a-z0-9]{2000,})" 1;
    "~*(&lt;|%0a|%0d|%27|%3c|%3e|%00|0x00)" 2;
    "~*((c99|php|web)shell|remoteview|site((.){0,2})copier)" 3;
    # ... much more mappings ...
  }
    
  set $7g_reason "";
  set $7g_blockme 0;
  if ($bad_ua_7g) {
    set $7g_reason "${7g_reason}:bad_ua_${bad_ua_7g}:"; 
    set $7g_blockme 1;
  }

  access_log /var/log/nginx/block.log full if=$7g_blockme;
  if ($7g_blockme = 1) {
    return 403;
  }

  [ ... locations etc ... ]

And this is my custom log format:
log_format full '$remote_addr [$time_iso8601] $status '
    '7gBlock "$7g_blockme" | '
    '7gRES "$7g_reason" | '
    'HOST-HDR "$host" | '
    'SRV $server_name:$server_port" | '
    'URI "$request_uri" | '
    'RFR "$http_referer" | '
    'UA "$http_user_agent"';

Finally a look into /var/log/nginx/block.log:
93.x.y.z [2024-08-09T11:12:40+02:00] 200 7gBlock "0" | 7gRES "" | HOST-HDR "mysite.com" | SRV mysite.com:443" | URI "/" | RFR "-" | UA "Mozilla/5.0...
93.x.y.z [2024-08-09T11:13:29+02:00] 403 7gBlock "1" | 7gRES ":bad_ua_3:" | HOST-HDR "mysite.com" | SRV mysite.com:443" | URI "/" | RFR "-" | UA "c99shell"

Line 2 is ok, it shows the bad useragent and that $7g_blockme is set to 1.
But line 1 is the problem: nginx logs into block.log even with $7g_blockme set to 0!!!
How could that ever be?? I am out of my nginx knowlegde now, sittin over a day on this problem

Nevermind. Workaround for me is now to use a rewrite in the if statement leading to an internal redirect to a special location that contains an access_log directive.
